# java sql date con request get parameter

Tags: mysql, date, jsp

disculpen la molestia, miren, tengo estos códigos:

```
public boolean requisitar(String solic, String empresa, String puesto, String correo, int folio, String preq, String zona, String region, 
            String sucursal, String trec, String tcon, String tjor, String justif, String psel, int pcaj, int cptp, String kpi, 
            String esc, String comp, String exp, String func, Date fecha) {
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            String consulta = "INSERT INTO requisicion (solicitante, empresa, puesto, correo, folio, puesreq, zona, region, sucursal, tiprec, tipcon, tipjor, justif, prodsel, prodcaj, comptp, kpi, esc, compet, exp, func, fecha) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

            ps = getConexion().prepareStatement(consulta);

            ps.setString(1, solic);
            ps.setString(2, empresa);
            ps.setString(3, puesto);
            ps.setString(4, correo);
            ps.setInt(5, folio);
            ps.setString(6, preq);
            ps.setString(7, zona);
            ps.setString(8, region);
            ps.setString(9, sucursal);
            ps.setString(10, trec);
            ps.setString(11, tcon);
            ps.setString(12, tjor);
            ps.setString(13, justif);
            ps.setString(14, psel);
            ps.setInt(15, pcaj);
            ps.setInt(16, cptp);
            ps.setString(17, kpi);
            ps.setString(18, esc);
            ps.setString(19, comp);
            ps.setString(20, exp);
            ps.setString(21, func);
            ps.setDate(22, fecha);

            if(ps.executeUpdate() == 1){
                return true;
            }
            

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Hay una excepción");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            try{
                if(getConexion() != null){
                    getConexion().close();
                }
                if(ps != null){
                    ps.close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Error: " + e);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Si, por si se habrán dado cuenta, resulta que PreparedStatement no permite el java util date, así que estoy lidiando con trabajar con java sql date, algo totalmente distinto a lo que venía llevando, mi dato mysql es un DATETIME por si lo preguntan, entonces estoy tratado de que me responda o más bien me requeste parametralmente la fecha, con el mismo dato java sql date, observen ahora en el servlet, lo intenté con java util, no permite siquiera castear para que no sugieran, no funciona, intenté engañar al sistema para que lo devolviera como string fecha pero por obvias razones tampoco funcionó pues el dato es un Date, hasta en eso que tonto fui, en fin, vean el código

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        
        String solic = request.getParameter("solicitante");
        String empresa = request.getParameter("empresa");
        String puesto = request.getParameter("puesto");
        String correo = request.getParameter("correo");
        int folio = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("folio"));
        String preq = request.getParameter("puesreq");
        String zona = request.getParameter("zona");
        String region = request.getParameter("region");
        String sucursal = request.getParameter("sucursal");
        String trec = request.getParameter("tiprec");
        String tcon = request.getParameter("tipcon");
        String tjor = request.getParameter("tipjor");
        String justif = request.getParameter("justif");
        String psel = request.getParameter("prodsel");
        int pcaj = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("prodcaj"));
        int cptp = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("comptp"));
        String kpi = request.getParameter("kpi");
        String esc = request.getParameter("esc");
        String comp = request.getParameter("compet");
        String exp = request.getParameter("exp");
        String func = request.getParameter("func");
        Date fecha = Date.valueOf(request.getParameter("fecha"));
//     java.util.Date f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(request.getParameter("fecha")); 
//        Date fecha = new Date(f.getTime());
//
        Consultas c = new Consultas();
        if(c.requisitar(solic, empresa, puesto, correo, folio, preq, zona, region, sucursal, trec, tcon, tjor, justif, psel, pcaj, cptp, kpi, esc, comp, exp, func, fecha)){
            response.sendRedirect("subirrequis.jsp");
        } else {
            out.println("No se pudieron subir los datos");
        }
    }
```

Por cierto lo que comenté viene que aquí mismo de la página de una "resolución" de jsp conversión del resultado request getparameter a la fecha, me parece que la página está en inglés, la traducí, de todos modos no me funcionó por si se dieron cuenta. Hay algo que también me tienen inquieto, no sé si en el jsp también tenga mucho que ver que estoy usando java util, miren, observen

```
<label>Fecha de elaboración: </label>
                <br><br>
                <input type="text" name="fecha" value='<%=currentDate%>' style='border-color: black' />

<script>
<%    
    Date dNow = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat ft = 
    new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String currentDate = ft.format(dNow);
%>
</script>
```

Este es el error que me devuelve

```
Severe:   java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (22 > number of parameters, which is 21).
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.checkBounds(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1396)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.getCoreParameterIndex(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1409)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.setString(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1776)
```

Lo del parámetro no les voy a mentir, ahí no tengo la más mínima idea, yo sabía que conforme agregabas los datos en una tabla en dicho orden, en ese orden los enumerabas con el preparedstatement, al menos que se inicie desde 0, pero que yo recuerde así no es el detalle.

Estuve pensando incluso cambiar el dato desde sql de DATETIME a VARCHAR, la verdad no sé que hacer y no sé si esto sea el motivo por el cual no me devuelve el dato, ojalá espero puedan ayudarme, de antemano muchas gracias al que vea la pregunta, que tengan buen día

Answer (score 0):

Tu insert espera recibir 21 parámetros (tienes 21 '?'):
String consulta = "INSERT INTO requisicion (solicitante, empresa, puesto, correo, folio, puesreq, zona, region, sucursal, tiprec, tipcon, tipjor, justif, prodsel, prodcaj, comptp, kpi, esc, compet, exp, func, fecha) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

Y estás pasando 22 parámetros.

Viendo los datos de las columnas de la tabla, te faltaría añadir un parámetro más (un '?' más) en el VALUES.

Un saludo.

Comment: si, eso vi, jejejeje, hace rato que estaba programando me di cuenta, gracias